# Does Mathematica have a function for the composite numbers not divisible by a squared prime?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, mathematica

I'm looking for a formula in Mathematica that gives me the sequence of integers whose prime decomposition is p1*p2*...*pn, that is, not divisible by any squared prime.
Does it even exist?

Comment: I want the sequence of composite numbers where each prime factor shows only once, examples: 2, 3, 6 (2*3), 15 (3*5), 105 (3*5*7). I don't want 4*3, 9*5, 25*11, etc.

Comment: That is, square free composites. I think I have a formula for the sum of the reciprocals of these numbers squared and I want to reconcile the 2.

Comment: It's usually called square-free numbers; maybe that will help your search

Comment: SquareFreeQ[n] gives True, if $n$ is a number you want. Your sum won't converge very rapidly, though. The sum is known to be $\zeta(2)/\zeta(4)=15/\pi^2$.

Comment: The sum of the reciprocals of the squared square-free numbers clearly is $\prod_{p}\left(1+\frac{1}{p^2}\right) = \prod_{p}\frac{1-\frac{1}{p^4}}{1-\frac{1}{p^2}}=\frac{\zeta(2)}{\zeta(4)}=\frac{15}{\pi^2}$ by Euler's product $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^s}=\prod_p\left(1-\frac{1}{p^s}\right)^{-1}$.

Comment: Thanks, yes, I used squareFree and PrimeNu in order to obtain the sums I was looking for. Thanks to all that helped.

Answer (score 3):

Wolfram Mathematica does have a built-in function that tells you if a number is prime, and it has a built-in function that tells you if a number is squarefree, but it doesn't have a built-in function that tells you if a number is composite *and* squarefree.

But you can very easily make your own. Here's one way out of many:

`sqrFreeCompQ[n_] := (SquareFreeQ[n] && (PrimeNu[n] > 1));`

(the difference between `PrimeNu` and `PrimeOmega` is irrelevant for this particular use)

I haven't tested this because my license server is acting funny today.

---

Just for a lark, I put the following into Wolfram Alpha:

`Sum[(1/n)Boole[SquareFreeQ[n] && (PrimeNu[n] > 1)], {n, Infinity}]`

Wolfram Alpha says that "by the harmonic series test, the series diverges." Then I tried changing `Infinity` to `1000`, it gives roughly $2.044313$ for the answer. But then I reread your comment so then I tried

`Sum[(1/n^2)Boole[SquareFreeQ[n] && (PrimeNu[n] > 1)], {n, Infinity}]`

but this is too much for Wolfram Alpha. Hopefully the technician fixes my license server tomorrow...

Comment: I was able to implement the "infinite" sum on Mathematica, it converges for the theoretical value expected.

Answer (score 2):

No, it doesn't, but you can easily make your own using just built-in functions.

`Select[Complement[Range[100], Prime[Range[PrimePi[100]]]], MoebiusMu[#] != 0 &]`

Not the most elegant, and perhaps not too adaptable to your purpose, but I hope it points you in the right direction.

Comment: What about SquareFreeQ[n]?

Comment: @ProfessorVector I don't know if that has a native implementation. For all I know, it could simply be `MoebiusMu[n] != 0` wrapped up.

Comment: Well, that's certainly how I would implement it! :)