# Are there alternative expressions for $\zeta(s)^{-k}, k>1$ and $k$ integer, like the one that uses Mobius for k=1?

Tags: number-theory, riemann-zeta, mobius-function

I've come across a way to generalize the Mobius function, and found that there's already so-called Mobius generalized functions (Apostol, 1970?, etc.)

However, my generalization is different from Apostol's it seems, plus it allows me to write $\zeta(s)^{-k}$ as a function of it, and I also can give a power series for it.

I am writing a paper on NT, which I hope to publish after I'm done typing it, and just want to make sure what is new and what is not.

Comment: Not sure what you mean exactly. There are formulas for $\zeta(s)$. If you raise them to the minus $k$, you have a formula. Such as: $$\zeta(s)^{-k} = \left( \sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-s} \right) ^{-k}$$ But you must mean something else?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen What does such  formula give for $\zeta(3)$ ? [Or is it just an equivalent form of it, not a "closed form"]

Comment: Thanks, what I really mean is whether there are other formulas expressing say $\zeta(s)^{-3}$ as a function of Mobius of order 3? See, $\zeta(s)^{-1}$ is expressed in a similar way as $\zeta(s)$, except that we remove some terms (square-ful) and we use -1 or +1 as coefficients of the square free. This should make it clear, let me know if not.

Comment: Multiplying Dirichlet series amounts to taking Dirichlet convolutions of their coefficients ([see here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_convolution#Dirichlet_series) if unfamiliar). As $\frac{1}{\zeta (s)} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\mu (n)}{n^s}$, This implies $\frac{1}{\zeta (s)^k} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\mu_k (n)}{n^s}$, where $\mu_k = \mu * ... * \mu$ taken $k$ times is [Popovici’s function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Möbius_function#Generalizations). Unless you have something wildly different, it is probably not new.

Comment: Thank you Paul. Ok, yes, so that was kind of a ice water bucket on me. Now, can you please tell me if the sum of cube-free numbers is explicitly known? It should, right, after all it stems from the generalization of $\zeta(s)^{-k}$. This is actually so simple I knew someone would have to notice it.

Comment: As pointed out by Jack D’Aurizio in a [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2638080/does-mathematica-have-a-function-for-the-composite-numbers-not-divisible-by-a-sq), for the sum of reciprocals of square-free numbers squared, we have an easily generalizable formula for the sum of $k$th power free numbers, call them $k$-free, $\sum_{n \textit{ k-free}} \frac{1}{n^s} = \Pi_{p \textit{ prime}} 1 + \frac{1}{p^s} + ... + \frac{1}{p^{(k-1)s}} = \Pi_{p \textit{ prime}} \frac{p^{ks}-1}{p^s-1} = \frac{\zeta (s)}{\zeta (ks)}$.

Comment: Perfect, haha, thank you. I know they say not to use "thank yous" here (which I think is kinda rude), but it seems they are reviewing that policy. Ok, thanks a lot, I wouldn't want to publish something thinking it's an original idea when it's not, but few people know about some more arcane topics, so we have to ask for help when we're not sure if something has already been thought of.

Comment: Paul, can you please answer the below question, I show one of my formulas in there: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2759231/sum-of-the-cube-free-numbers-sum-k-1-infty-frac-mu-2kk2s